# How to "ping" from my ubuntu linux server to a PC with Windows 8?

Tags: server, 14.04

When you can give me a solution would greatly appreciate it, I have my tower server with linux (ubuntu 14.04) and I have tried my server ping the pc where I installed a program. Net and I need you on the server saving files necessary for enrollment in my school, my pc with windows 8 pinging the server but the server does not ping my pc and add exceptions in the firewall on both machines and even haci no pings and makes it impossible for my enter the program database mysql this check in linux, I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Could you mention the complete command you are using to ping?

Comment: ping 192.168.6.109 the same used in windows and looking out the command and q me was that

Comment: Can you also include ifconfig, and how the computers are networked together. If you could update your question with this information it would be easier to answer.

Comment: even after several tests the connection problem continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux and Windows (and Mac, etc) all use the same command `ping`, however, there are some slight differences in the execution of the command. In Windows, you will need to do a `ping -t` to have a similar effect to the `ping` command in Linux, i.e. continuous pinging until CTRL-C is pressed.

If you are not getting a response from your Windows machine, that means that either the firewall is running and blocking ICMP requests, your network settings are incorrectly configured or there is no network route between your Linux and Windows server (assuming they are physically or wirelessly connected to each other).

Comment: and perform the ping in windows has the ip of ubuntu server and windows if you receive server response to the problem is to ping the server receives no response from pc with windows and perform the ping-t nothing

Comment: Your English isn't really good, I don't get what exactly you mean. Can you post the full commands with prompts and output so we can see from which machine to which machine you're trying to ping?

Comment: Sorry, I'm from Costa Rica and I can hardly speak English, I mean, my computer with Windows 8 if you ping the server, but not vice versa

Comment: I thought that if it had been fixed, but not yet

Comment: If your problem persists and you don't know how to explain it properly in English, there's a Spanish Ubuntu forum as well: http://www.ubuntu-es.org/forum#.U6hhQdRdXQo